# Does DNN CE 7.x support programmatic uploading of files to secure folders?

Tags: dotnetnuke

Does DNN CE 7.x support programmatic uploading of files to already defined secure folders?
I need to bulk upload thousands of file for a large user population (>1500 users).

For each file, at the time of the upload, I must assign specific READ rights for every  user.

Then, I need to have a page (DNN module?) where after each user logs on to the system they will be able to visit their page and click to download any of their *own* files.

Please note that the files are private to every user and no user must be able to view files of another user. Of course, search engines must not be able to index such content.

Is there anything OOTB to support that, or, I shall need to write a DNN module to allow the users to bulk upload files to a secure folder and then another DNN module to list the list of files for each user?

Can this be done with DNN CE 7.x version, or I need to buy DNN Pro 7.x ?

Thank you for any help/insight you can provide.
Regards,
P.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with CE, but it will require custom development to implement. The FILE system API for DNN should allow you to do all this from a development perspective.